# How do I start Unicorn using systemd/systemctl?

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundler, unicorn, systemd

I've wrote a `systemd` file for `systemctl` to start `unicorn`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unicorn server

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=my-app-unicorn
User=deployer
PIDFile=/tmp/unicorn.my-app.pid
WorkingDirectory=/opt/www/my-app.com

ExecStart=/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my-app/bin/bundle exec "unicorn_rails -D -c /opt/www/my-app.com/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
#ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s USR2 $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here are the commands I used to start the service

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start my-app.service
```

Here I check the status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status my-app
● my-app.service - My app unicorn server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/my-app.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-03-15 14:56:31 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 22165 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
  Process: 22162 ExecStart=/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my-app/bin/bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -c /opt/www/my-app.com/config/unicorn.rb -E production (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 22162 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Mar 15 14:56:31 fat-man systemd[1]: Started My-App unicorn server.
Mar 15 14:56:31 fat-man systemd[22162]: my-app.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my-app/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
Mar 15 14:56:31 fat-man systemd[1]: my-app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Mar 15 14:56:31 fat-man systemd[1]: my-app.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=200
Mar 15 14:56:31 fat-man systemd[1]: my-app.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 15 14:56:31 fat-man systemd[1]: my-app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Multi-posted to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270043/ .  [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 4):

Error message `Failed at step CHDIR` means that `systemd` is unable to `cd` into directory specified in `WorkingDirectory`. It is specified as `/opt/www/my-app.com` but later you list it as `/opt/www/my-app`.

Another issue is that you are starting `unicorn_rails` with option `-D` which tells `unicorn_rails` process to daemonize (started process forks child and immediately exits) but your `[Service]` section doesn't specify `Type` so it defaults to `simple` and `systemd` expects process to stay alive. You need to remove `-D` option or specify `Type=forking`.

See example [unit file for unicorn](https://gist.github.com/AlexeyDemidov/77a2791ab75426bc7776d4bdc7c588b4)